# SQL: Join 2 tables and return multiple rows from second table based on key of first table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table 'Customers', with a key of customerid.

There is another table PaymentTotals which also has a customerid column. This table stores amounts paid by a customer (PaymentAmount) in a given week (weeknumber field). This implies that in the PaymentTotals table there may be several rows for any one customerid, the difference being the weeknumber for any of these rows.

I am trying to build a query in MSSQL that joins the two tables and will return for a given customerid the PaymentAmount for each different weeknumber.

It is not clear to me how to build this query. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty basic `join` query.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers C INNER JOIN PaymentTotals PT
ON   C.customerid  = PT.customerid
```

If you have multiple Payments made by one customer in a given week and want to get total by week you could do something like ....

```
SELECT C.customerid  
      ,PT.WeekNumber
      ,SUM(PT.Payment_Column) AS TotalPayment
FROM Customers C INNER JOIN PaymentTotals PT
ON   C.customerid  = PT.customerid 
GROUP BY C.customerid, PT.WeekNumber
```